# web api post is not working where get is

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Ive got the following controller in Web.API.

I can call GetCartItems without any problem, however when I try to POST to addtocart it says the resource is not found.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/cart")]
public class CartController : ApiController
{


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("addtocart")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddToCart(string assetId)
    {

        return Ok();
    }

    [Route("getcartitems")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCartItems()
    {
        List<dynamic> cartItems = new List<dynamic>();

        cartItems.Add(new { AssetId = "1", AssetName ="Airstream", Points=60});

        return Ok(cartItems);
    }

}
```

Here is my angular code:

```
var data = { "assetId": id };
    $http.post(
        serviceBase + 'api/cart/addtocart',
        JSON.stringify(data),
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    ).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: can you provide the code you are using to perform the GET request? maybe that will give some insight on the issue if there's a difference between both requests.

Comment: I found the answer here.   
I had to pass the assetId in the querystring not as a post unless I use model binding.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145152/mvc-web-api-posting-json-data-gives-me-a-404?rq=1